# Formatting a byte array as a C-89 initializer expression in LLDB

Tags: c, arrays, formatting, lldb

I have an array which is initialized with a regular C89 initializer:

```
uint8_t data[] = {0x05,0x48,0x45,0x4c,0x4c,0x4f,0x01,0x00 ... }
```

When I print this array in lldb, I get this monstrosity:

```
   (lldb) p data
(uint8_t [200]) $0 = {
  [0] = '\x05'
  [1] = 'H'
  [2] = 'E'
  [3] = 'L'
  [4] = 'L'
  [5] = 'O'
  [6] = '\x01' 
  ...
```

I'm trying to coerce lldb's output into the original C89 syntax so I can simply paste contents of the array from lldb back into my code (e.g. so I can write unit tests that use arrays I catch during debugging).

How can I tell lldb to format its output to look like a normal C89 initializer?

Comment: I don't now but try this doc http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html Look at that example that prints the array in a simple format to see how it can be done. Otherwise maybe try to write your own custom format

Answer (score 0):

Use `type format add -f x uint8_t` to get nearly what you want:

```
(lldb) p data
(uint8_t [8]) $4 = {
  [0] = 0x05
  [1] = 0x48
  [2] = 0x45
  [3] = 0x4c
  [4] = 0x4c
  [5] = 0x4f
  [6] = 0x01
  [7] = 0x00
}
```

You just need to add "," after each line to have a source code line (for the array) that will compile. If this is too bothersome, I suspect you will have to write something in python.

To see what other formats (besides "x" used above, which stands for hex), use `help format`.

EDIT: following Brandin's hint above, it turns out you can format your array in the way that you want by additionally using

```
(lldb) type summary add --summary-string "," uint8_t
```

This will add a "," after each line:

```
(lldb) p data
(uint8_t [8]) $3 = {
  [0] = 0x05 ,
  [1] = 0x48 ,
  [2] = 0x45 ,
  [3] = 0x4c ,
  [4] = 0x4c ,
  [5] = 0x4f ,
  [6] = 0x01 ,
  [7] = 0x00 ,
}
```

which you can copy & paste 1:1 into your source code (final semicolon needs to be added of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a python summary printer to print the contents of the array in the correct format but the `SBValue` object that is passed in to the python won't have the name of the variable available.

```
(lldb) type summ add uint8_t[] -P
[...]
     print '{',
     for i in xrange(0, valobj.GetNumChildren()):
       print '0x%02x' % valobj.GetChildAtIndex(i).GetValueAsUnsigned(),
       if (i != valobj.GetNumChildren() - 1):
         print ',',
     print '};'
     DONE 

(lldb) p data
{ 0x05 , 0x48 , 0x45 , 0x4c , 0x4c , 0x4f , 0x01 , 0x00 };
(uint8_t [8]) $1 = {
  [0] = 0x05
  [1] = 0x48
  [2] = 0x45
  [3] = 0x4c
  [4] = 0x4c
  [5] = 0x4f
  [6] = 0x01
  [7] = 0x00
}
```

Comment: And if you add the "-v" flag to the "type summary add" command it will only show the summary, and not the redundant array version.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way to get pretty much the same thing Jason showed without having to know any Python is to use the -c and -O options to type summary add, like:

```
(lldb) type summary add -c -O uint8_t[]
(lldb) expr array
(uint8_t [8]) $2 = ('\x01', '\x02', '\x03', '\x04', '\x05', '\x06', '\a', '\b')
```

This is generally useful if you have some type that you just want to view all the elements of a structure or array "flat" like this rather than in turned out form.